# Find a function $g(x,y)$ that satisfies the following conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the function $g(x,y)$, that is continuous at $(0,0)$ but the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ do not exist.

Comment: This is one, there may be others: $f(x,y)=\sqrt x+\sqrt y$

Answer (score 0):

As Emmad already pointed out $g(x,y)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ is obviously continuous at $(0,0)$ and with

$$\nabla g(x,y)=\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\right)^T$$

you see that it can't be derived at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=\sin\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)+\cos\left(y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right) $

Comment: oh, I edit it, typo. thank you very much